# Nothing happens when using register_activation_hook in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

Hiya I am trying to create a plugin in wordpress.
The aim is it will create a table in the database, however even by just adding an echo inside the hook it seems that this does not get triggered.
wp version 6.11, mysql 8.0.16, php 8.1.9

Folder structure is
wp-content
|____ plugins
|****my_plugin
|**** index.php

To follow, this is what is inside  the index.php,
I've tried also an external function, but nothing.
If the echo is outside then I can see it.
Debugging is enabled and no error are thrown.

Any ideas? Thanks

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: test tickles
*/

echo(LOG_ERR. 'Testing @ ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . __FILE__ . "<br>");
echo(LOG_ERR.'WP_PLUGIN_DIR = ' . WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "<br>");
echo(LOG_ERR.'plugin base name = ' . plugin_basename(__FILE__) . "<br>");

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function() {
    echo "poo";
});
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't run on every page load - in case that's what you're expecting.  It will only run when the plugin is initially activated - so to test, you will need to deactivate and then re-activate your plugin.

Also, please note that the activation hook does not work with mu-plugins.

The documentation also mentions a redirect - so you may want to try `die('my plugin activated');` instead of just `echo`.

[Relevant part of docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20plugin%20is%20activated%2C%20all%20active%20plugins%20are%20loaded%2C%20then%20the%20plugin%20is%20activated.%20The%20plugin%E2%80%99s%20activation%20hook%20is%20run)

Comment: As commented above I have removed all echoes except the one inside... also have added the die statement as per suggestion, but nothing happens

Comment: And just to confirm @johnbell you are deactivating the plugin, then re-activating it to test?

Comment: aye, I think I fixed it by moving the register_activation_hook in the main file of my plugin, it only seems to work there

Answer (score 0):

To see the output of your plugin, remove **LOG_ERR** from your echo statements.

Your code should look like this, please try this hope it should work:

```
<?php
/**
Plugin Name: test tickles
*/

echo('Testing @ ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ' ' . __FILE__ . "<br>");
echo('WP_PLUGIN_DIR = ' . WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "<br>");
echo('plugin base name = ' . plugin_basename(__FILE__) . "<br>");

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function() {
echo "poo";
});
?>
```

Comment: I have removed all the echoes at the top and changed to

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, function() {
 echo "poo";
 die('poo');
});

nothing is shown, php doesn't die.